# Sed regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to do a set of substitution within the text file 
E.g putting instead of following key string

```
#include "martini.itp"
```

3 another strings with accurate paths to the itp files

```
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini1.itp"
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini2.itp"
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini3.itp"
```

I have tried to realize it using below pattern which produced errors I guess because the characters like ../ should be isolated from sed statement using specified syntax.

```
sed -i 's/#include "martini.itp"/#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_lipids_all_201506.itp"\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_ions.itp"\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_solvents.itp"/' topol.top
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape spaces as well? `\ `

Comment: You need to either use different delimiters for the substitution or escape all the forward slashes.

Comment: right I need to escape ../ within the SED statement. How I could do it correctly on my example 7

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with fixed strings, you can just use awk and avoid having to escape anything (well, except some double quotes):

```
awk '$0 == "#include \"martini.itp\"" { 
    $0 = "#include \"../dir1/dir2/martini1.itp\"" ORS \
         "#include \"../dir1/dir2/martini2.itp\"" ORS \
         "#include \"../dir1/dir2/martini3.itp\""
}
{ print }' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If the line matches, replace it with the other lines. A quite common shorthand is to replace `{ print }` with `1`, as `1` is true and `{ print }` is the default action.

To use sed, I'd go for something like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/#include "martini\.itp"/i\
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini1.itp"\
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini2.itp"\
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini3.itp"
d' file
```

This inserts the lines you want, then `d` deletes the original line. Using `-i.bak` creates a backup of your original file, which is something I'd always recommend.

Comment: You can use a single print statement in the first part and maintain readability

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `.` by writing `\.` and change regex delimiter from `/` to `:` just to prevent some problem of regex delimiter collision with your file path. So finally, you should get something like this:

Regex:

```
$'s:#include "martini\.itp":#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_lipids_all_201506.itp"\\\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_ions.itp"\\\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_solvents.itp":'
```

Run:

```
sed -i '' $'s:#include "martini\.itp":#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_lipids_all_201506.itp"\\\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_ions.itp"\\\n#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_solvents.itp":' topol.top
```

Output:

```
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_lipids_all_201506.itp"
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_ions.itp"
#include "../dir1/dir2/martini_v2.0_solvents.itp"
```

Note that there is some trick here to escape `newline` by adding `$` to the beginning of regex and use `\\\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.`s i nthe replacement part.

Comment: You also don't need to triple escape the newlines. `\n` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the " . ' and / characters by putting \ before each instance. Also '$'/n for the newline

```
sed -i 's/#include \"martini\.itp\"/#include \"\.\.\/dir1\/dir2\/martini1.itp\"'$'\\n#include \"\.\.\/dir1\/dir2\/martini2.itp\"\\n#include \"\.\.\/dir1\/dir2\/martini3.itp\"/g' topol.top
```